# actionscript playing 10 sounds from library one after another

Tags: audio, actionscript, playback

I have a lot of sounds in my library. I randomly choose 10 of them and I have their names in an array.
The problem is that in air android I cant play them one after the other. I found some codes that play two of them but not more.

Comment: It will improve your chances of getting a useful reply if you show the code you have and explain how it fails.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some advice on how best to  show your code.  You should also explain what happens after two files have been played - does your code just stop, or fail with some error or what?  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more ideas about how to ask questions that are easier to answer.

Comment: There is a code I found here:                                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443686/how-do-you-loop-a-sound-in-flash-as3-when-it-ends                   but it doesn't work for 10 different sounds.

Comment: There are six different fragments on code in [that thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443686/how-do-you-loop-a-sound-in-flash-as3-when-it-ends) and of course none of them try to play ten different sounds.  It's possible some readers might take the time to work through the other thread and to guess what changes you made to the code found there - but most readers will just skip over your question to the next one.  It will really help if you edit your original post to add a minimal example of the code you are using and a description of how that code fails.