# Play continuous sound no matter where you are on the timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible in flash to keep playing the same sound even if I jump to new frames on the timeline but the sound doesn't jump.

Comment: Of course it's possible but only by code not when working with frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have your sound file in the first frame, select the frame with the sound in it and look at the properties tab, there is a drop-down window that says sound, inside is a sync option, set it to start and loop. That seems to make it play indefinitely.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it grammatically 
check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443790/3623547

Comment: This is an uneducated answer, you should have read my comment. Voted down. Of course sounds added to the timeline can only play while this timeline is running, once the timeline jumps or is removed the sounds stops which is precisely what the question was about.

Comment: I believe if the Sync is set to event the sound will keep playing if you jump around in the timeline, but not sure what happens if you jump to another scene. And it is very hard to control it (fade, stop etc). So yeah programmatic way is better

Comment: @BotMaster, but doesn't the small print at the bottom (link) fix that concern?

Comment: What do you mean "once the timeline jumps or is removed the sounds stops"  It keeps playing even if it jumps to another frame or remove the movieclip. I tested it before answering your question .  the Sync is set to "event" not "stream".